# Customization to Last Week filter

Tags: filter, salesforce, customization, reporting

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a custom filter on a report that will show opportunities created from Thursday to Wednesday?

Currently, I'm using "Last Week" as the filter but for forecasting purposes I've been asked to show data from a Thursday to a Wednesday.

Comment: Welcome :) But StackOverflow is focused on coding, programming challenges. Admin/config questions will reach better audience at dedicated https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ooo, interesting one!

How "serious" this is. Is only 1 department/team/whatever in whole salesforce org operating with such weeks or more like whole company? If you're in manufacturing business for example you may have company-wide https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%E2%80%934%E2%80%935_calendar, something similar?

There's something but it's a bit of nuclear option. Make a fresh empty sandbox and experiment with it there, **don't enable it straight in prod or even your usual test environment**.
In Setup -> Fiscal Year you can define your custom years, "quarters", "months" and weeks. You could use that to decide week starts on Thursday.
[image: config panel for custom 2024 that starts on 1st Thursday of the gregorian year] [image: preview mode of the generated calendar]

And then you may have seen report filters or group by "Fiscal week", FY (fiscal year)...
[image: report filtered by current fiscal week][image: report grouped by date, by FW]

Again - this is a powerful but nuclear option. You can have only 1 Fiscal calendar like that so it has to work for whole company. All reports will have option to use normal (Gregorian) calendar or this. It's also possible to use it in Apex, SOQL easily... but there's no going back. Once you enable custom year you can never go back. If 5 years down the line a merger happens or somebody changes their mind - you can make a custom calendar for 2029 that will be "normal" (start Jan 1st and stuff) - but it'll still be custom.

If it sounds like too much you may want to experiment with some date functions? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5 maybe you could abuse "Day of the Week" one to determine "last Thursday" and then filter by created date >= that in the report... It'd be only good for filter though, if it sounds like you need group by "week"... either that Fiscal Year stuff or something based  on "Find the Week of the Year a Date Is In" trick?

Comment: THANK YOU so very much! I will try this today - appreciate your insight and time.